# ServerSocket on port 80 is it correct?

Tags: java, serversocket

I read some materials about ServerSocket and tried to listen on port 80 and print for example InetAddress of website which I was opening in web browser but my program couldn't do this. My code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Site implements Runnable {
    private int port;
    Site(int port){
        this.port = port;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            while(true){
                Socket socket = server.accept();
                System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Site(80));
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

When I run my program I am only one time in the while loop and the program doesn't print `System.out.println(socket.getInetAddress())` and as the result when I open my web browser and visit http sites I don't see any output. Do you know what I am doing wrong? Do you know any other ways to print InetAddress for currently open website? Any materials will by appreciate.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I don't get it.

Comment: Your program looks like it ought to work. What happens when you run it? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: 'Couldn't do it' isn't a problem description. Post the error, exception, stack trace, unexpected behaviour, whatsover it is. Edit it into your question. NB you do need to close accepted sockets.

Comment: After you start it, how specifically are you testing it?

Comment: I insert two `System.out.println("test")` between `Socket socket = server.accept() ` and there something goes wrong because the second output doesn't print or maybe I think wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment without proper reputation so forgive me for throwing everything out here:
you might already have something listening on port 80
you might be running on a version of linux that restricts non root process binding to ports above 1024
you might be blocked by a software firewall

Comment: I can comment on my answer though :) can you post the error?